# AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID causing volume does not change using physical volume control buttons on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios6

I am in urgent need of the the geeks present on this forum regarding the iOS SDK questions.I have an app in which i hav to play multiple sounds simultaneously.I started with AVAudioplayer class but i realise that it was getting hung on iPhone 3gs and older iOS versions so i moved to  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)afUrl,&soundID) from the tips of one of my friend.Now the app plays sound seamlessly on both iPhone and iPad .I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 5.1.1 and i have updated the Ipad 2 from iOS 5.1.1 to latest iOS 6.0 stable.Now the problem is that  the app runs fine on iPhone but on iPad a strange issue comeing up.On iPad sound is played but the volume does not change with Physical volume change button effect.I have build the app using Xcode 4.5 GM with iOS 6.0 and have set the deployment target to iOS 5.0 .
Please help me out as i am getting crazy on this strange behavior on Ipad only ..I hope i would definitely get the perfect solution here from you guys !!
Thanks in Advance !!!!